# How to prove the determinant of resistance matrix $R$?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Let $G$ be a connected graph with $n$ vertices, $R$ be the resistance matrix of $G$, $\tau$ be the $n\times 1$vector with components $\tau_1,\tau_2,...\tau_n$,and $\tau_i=2-\sum\limits_{j\thicksim i} \frac{r(i,j)}{w(i,j)}$ for$i=1,2,...,n$. Let $\kappa (G)$ be the sum of the weights of all the spanning trees of $G$. How to prove $det R=(-1)^{n-1}2^{n-3}\frac {\tau' R \tau}{\kappa (G)}$. And which articles can I reference?

Comment: Are you looking for [Resistance matrix of a weighted graph &emsp; Page 5,Theorem 3](https://match.pmf.kg.ac.rs/electronic_versions/Match50/match50_73-82.pdf) where the weghts of edges are all real numbers.       By the way, for "the weights are positive definite matrix of same size" case, you can refer to [Resistance matrices of graphs with matrix weights &emsp; Page 13,Theorem 4.2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.01325.pdf)